# Is it possible to create function that in one case return object and on another case not return anything?

Tags: kotlin

In my Kotlin project I create function:

```
fun myFun(isAsync: Boolean) {
  ...
}
```

But I need the next behavior of this function:

1. If `isAsync = true` then return some object, e.g. "hello world"
2. If `isAsync = false` then not return anything

Is it possible in Kotlin?

Comment: How would you "not return anything"? Could you return `null`?

Comment: it smells not good

Comment: `fun myFun(isAsync : Boolean) = "hello world".takeIf { isAsync }` if you want to spare some characters ;-) ... but... what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a nullable object type like `String?`

```
fun myFun(isAsync: Boolean): String? {
    return if (isAsync) {
        "test"
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

anyways you should handle it at the call site

```
val result = myFyn(isAsync)
```

Comment: You  forgot to add return type in function interface. This is correct: "fun myFun(isAsync: Boolean): String? {..."